# Mongoid recursively find embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

What is the best way to find a recursively embedded document?

I have the following setup:

Group embeds many posts.
Post recursively embeds many posts.

Given an id of a post embedded object, is there a built-in way to recursively search this entire tree structure?

My current implementation is essentially a breadth first search, but I was curious whether mongodb/mongoid has more efficient implementation.

Comment: If you need simpler queries, you should reference posts (rather than embed).

Comment: @nan What's the status of your solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

The current [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common) mentions that it is possible and shows how to do that, see section *Recursive Embedding*. This works only on embedded documents.